# Place HTML popover in a flexbox parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I added a popover to a page and it is unaffected by any CSS applied to its ancestors.

How can I place the popover at the bottom of the viewport by using a flexbox parent element like this:

```css
#popoverparent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  z-index: 1;
}

#mypopover {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="popoverparent">
  <div id="mypopover" popover="manual">
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p><button popovertarget="mypopover" popovertargetaction="toggle">Close</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that can work for you.

For example,

index.html

```html
    <div class="flex-container">
       <div id="mypopover" popover="manual">
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p><button popovertarget="mypopover" popovertargetaction="toggle">Close</button></p>
    </div>
```

style.css

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1; /*It determines how a flex item will distribute the available free space among other flex items.*/
}

#mypopover {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

I hope it works

Comment: It does work (even without `flex-grow`), thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The answer to my question is using identical `z-index` values for parent and popover. Ali's answer helped with the actual positioning.